# fosfacebook bundle unable to get user information from facebook

Tags: facebook, symfony, symfony-2.1, fosuserbundle, fosfacebookbundle

I'm using Symfony 2.1 for a project & I'm using FOSFacebook bundle integrated with FOSUser bundle. when the user logs into my application no information is retrieved! i mean this line goes in exception :

```
namespace Acmes\UserBundle\Security\User\Provider;
class FacebookProvider implements UserProviderInterface {
//...
public function loadUserByUsername($username) {
 //...
 try {
       $fbdata = $this->facebook->api('/me');
   } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
       $fbdata = null;
     }
 //...
```

}
}
when the user logs in, the button change to 'logout' but i get the error :

```
"The user is not authenticated on facebook"
```

which means that $fbdata is null & no info has returned back from facebook application.

any solution? thanks!:)

Comment: have you read the exception message ? maybe you misconfigured your facebook app

Comment: @JulienRollin,thanks for your answer,I think that I've checked every thing, but to ensure,is there any documentation which says how to config facebook application for using in this way?

Comment: have you put the twig helper "facebook_initialize"  in your layout/template ?  Are you connected to facebook in an another tab ? Facebook php sdk uses a session cookie to know if you are connected

Comment: yes!and as i said the login button changes to logout button + after that user is authenticated in facebook in other tabs..  :(

Comment: ok...so, check your app configuration in facebook (sandbox? allowed domain ?), remove all your cookies, and maybe remove access to your app in your facebook app pages ( "page settings" > tab "application") ? As it, you will retest the whole auth process :)

Comment: should the sandbox mode be enable?any way it doesn't change.. :(
thanks for your answers!:)

Comment: i enabled the sandbox mode(but it can't be enabled for ever of-course)
and the user is authenticated by his facebook id but not integrated in database!

Comment: the steps are: retrieve facebookid, check if user exists whith this id or create it, add/update facebook infos you need, thats it in 'loadUserByUsername'

Comment: i have dumped the FacebookApiException,like this:
    `var_dump($e);`
and the result was :
    `'message' => string 'couldn't connect to host' (length=24)
    'type' => string 'CurlException' (length=13)`

Comment: are you on shared host ?  it seems a curl config limitation

Comment: now i'm testing my application on local (using WAMP)

Comment: the problem fixed.it was my vpn problem...
how can i set this question as fixed?delete it?

Comment: i would at least close it, but you should delete it, because you did not expose you misconfiguration

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem as yours. 
Something must go wrong during your installation process of fosuserbundle and fosfacebook bundle.
Double check your settings with the following tutorial.
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md